# Extracting data tables from website

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to extract a data table from a website. Pandas read_html is giving a HTTP error 403. Is there any other module through which I can extract the data by python.

Here is the website: https://pakstockexchange.com/stock2/index_new.php?section=research&page=show_price_table_new&symbol=ABOT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mask your session as if you were using a browser:

```
import requests

header = {
  "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.75 Safari/537.36",
  "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
}

r = requests.get(url, headers=header)

dfs = pd.read_html(r.text)
```

Comment: It does a perfect job of reading page, but I just want it to read the data table. Any way to achieve that?

Comment: Got the solution dfs=dfs[6] does the job.